# I need a command line to count the number of characters between a pattern repeated in a XML file

Tags: xml, bash

I have a file (XML) and I need to count the number of characters between a pattern (tag) and it pattern is repeated in the file.

The pattern is:

```
<controlfield tag="001">
```

Example XML file content:

```
<datafield tag="650" ind1="0" ind2="4">
   <subfield code="a">xxx</subfield>
   <subfield code="x">sdf</subfield>
 </datafield>
 <datafield tag="650" ind1="0" ind2="4">
   <subfield code="a">fff</subfield>
 </datafield>
 <datafield tag="650" ind1="0" ind2="4">
   <subfield code="a">asdfaf</subfield>
   <subfield code="x">fdfdf</subfield>
   <subfield code="x">dfdfdf</subfield>
 </datafield>
<controlfield tag="001">000000355</controlfield>
<datafield tag="909" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
  <subfield code="a">AGR01</subfield>
  <subfield code="b">ph</subfield>
  <subfield code="c">AGRP</subfield>
</datafield>
<datafield tag="910" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
  <subfield code="a">AGR</subfield>
</datafield>
<controlfield tag="001">000000358</controlfield>
<datafield tag="590" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
  <subfield code="a">19. dfsdfs em 2015</subfield>
  <subfield code="w">CECLI</subfield>
</datafield>
<datafield tag="650" ind1="0" ind2="4">
  <subfield code="a">Topografia</subfield>
</datafield>
<controlfield tag="001">000000365</controlfield>
```

I read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295332/i-need-the-counts-of-lines-between-two-matching-patterns and try:

```
sed -n '/tag="001"/,/tag="001"/p' file.xml | wc -l
```

But only one counter was printed.

I need a counter for each pattern occurrence, in the above example I need 3 counters:

1. number of characters before

   ```
   <controlfield tag="001">000000355</controlfield>
   ```
2. number of characters between

   ```
   <controlfield tag="001">000000355</controlfield>
   ```

   and

   ```
   <controlfield tag="001">000000358</controlfield>
   ```
3. number of characters between

   ```
   <controlfield tag="001">000000358</controlfield>
   ```

   and

   ```
   <controlfield tag="001">000000365</controlfield>
   ```

Can you help me?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I see variations of this question --and their answers in awk-- flashing by every day.

Comment: I would take a look to see if xmlstarlet would be able to handle this. Also, your title says "number of characters", but `wc -l` counts _lines_.

Comment: Also, `wc` is going to only output _one_ total count for _all_ the input it's given. It has no idea about the structure of your data.

Answer (score 2):

with GNU `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS="<controlfield tag=\"001\">[0-9]+</controlfield>" '{print length()}' file

394
253
239
1
```

the last 1 is for the last line feed.  You may want to remove the line feeds before the length is calculated.